# Angular2 : concurrent is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: node.js, typescript, webserver, development-environment, angular

While running server for angular2 using npm start is giving error that concurrent is not recognized as internal or external command, why is it happens these kind of error

here is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "contactlistapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The app",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "tsc": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "tsc:w": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc -w",
    "serve": "./node_modules/.bin/live-server --host=localhost --port=3000 .",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run serve\" "
  },
  "author": "Sarah",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.1",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3"
  }
}
```

structure of the project is there is node_module and typings folder there is app.ts file for server(empty only express is imported), and component.ts(and their .js), tsconfig.json

Comment: did you run npm install already?

Comment: yes, and accedently second time also

Comment: reinstalling modules after deleting node_module folder, now error is live-server is not recognized as external or internal command

Comment: your dependency is `lite-server` not `live-server`

Comment: but the error is about live-server

Comment: you are installing `lite-server` but you are calling `live-server`, you are not installing `live-server`, call `lite-server` instead: change `"serve": "./node_modules/.bin/live-server --host=localhost --port=3000 .",` for `"serve": "./node_modules/.bin/lite-server --host=localhost --port=3000 ."`

Comment: Thanks mate, why it happend automatically

Comment: I didnt change anything like replacing lite with live, is it npm problem?

Comment: you just mistyped the `t` for a `v` most likely.

Comment: How can I say thank you :)

Comment: Just marking the answer as accepted would be enough ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> concurrent is not recognized as internal or external command

Must likely you haven't ran `npm install` since you added the `"concurrently": "^1.0.0"` dependency.

> live-server is not recognized as external or internal command

You are installing the `lite-server` :

`"lite-server": "^1.3.1"`

yet you are calling the `live-server`:

`"serve": "./node_modules/.bin/live-server --host=localhost --port=3000 ."`

call `lite-server` instead.